# Custom listview for image and text, or only text

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app of my website(Just new to programming Java), getting data from my site is all going fine, but now i need to display it. I did some research online for the best way to do it(CustomListView), but coundnt find the solution yet, hope you guys can help me out.

The site i'm making an app of, is just a site where people can post text, or text with a photo.
Getting the text in my listview is going fine, but i also need images to display. 
The problem is, how can i tell the Listview that it only contains text, so it wont display any image field, and how can i tell the ListView when there is a photo found by the post,that it also should display that one?

Comment: In the layout you send to the ListView, you should need to create a imatgeView with `visibiity = GONE` and when you ask for the post data (if image != null) just set the imatge in the imageView and setVisibility = visible

Comment: use recyclerview instead of listview as recyclerview adpater have viewtype . using view type you can differentiate the viewholder(viewholder==a singler row).. so in your case you have two view types one with text only and on with textview and imageview .. NOTE: each view type have its corresponding veiwholder..

Comment: Refrence to my answer : https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example

Comment: This seems to be the solution i was looking for, thank you Adeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tag if the post contains an image or not for example if the data is in JSON form just set a tag

```
[{contains_image:"null"},{contains_image:"yes"}]
```

Then in your adapter check this tag if the result is a null set visibility gone

Comment: It took me some time before i get this. But after some thinking and trying, i found out what u ment. This one also works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a layout containing a listView.
2. You have to create an xml lyout corresponding to one row of your list view.
3. You have to create an adapter which will populate data to insert in your listView
4. You have to create an onClickListener on your button to add data in your list
5. If you are using an ArrayAdapter or a CursorAdapter, add the new item you created to the list or the cursor used by your adapter and (notifyDataSetChanged() is automatically called), so your adapter will update the listview

Source :  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Have at look at this article : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Once you are go through with above set placeholder image which will be show for the items that do no get dynamic images from your server response.